# Virtual Network User Mode Linux

Tags: linux

In VNUML(Virtual Network User Mode Linux)I have created 5 UML using an XML file but I cant figure out how to mount the UMLs(User Mode Linux) filesystem on the host computer  having Ubuntu OS (opensource)? I mounted the host file system in each UML but vice versa i want to do

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with bare UML, it just does not provide this feature.

So you will have to install some kind of server inside the UML guest so it can be accessed from the host. Generally one would go for SAMBA (fairly straightforward to setup) or NFS (harder imo), but there are a multitude of options there, even some esoteric ones like sshfs which are very easy to setup and may just be the ticket for you.